# Remove multiple containers from docker from Windows cmd

Tags: docker, docker-container

I want to remove multiple containers at a time using windows cmd I have used docker rm | docker ps -a -q but not working. Anyone, please help me on this.

docker rm $ (docker ps -a -q) this is not working on windows.

Answer (score 4):

it's removing only stopped containers. You first stop the containers and then remove them using your command or forcefully remove them, also, check this out, this [thread](https://gist.github.com/evanscottgray/8571828), as well [docker system prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)

```
$ docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
$ docker rm $ (docker ps -a -q)
```

Hope this works on Windows cmd as well.

Comment: Showing error C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a
See 'docker stop --help'.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>

Comment: @saba: Okay, my bad... I think, for this you need Git bash or cygwin, docker toolbox ship it's terminal along.

Comment: Thanks for your help I got a solution if we use Windows Powershell, command will run fine.I post the answer separately to find the answer easily

Comment: you can force to stop and remove in one line -> $ docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)

Answer (score 3):

Use Windows powershell to run this command `docker rm $ (docker ps -a -q)`

Comment: Works in PowerShell but only removes stopped containers.  You'd need to execute command `docker stop $(docker ps -aq)` first to stop all containers.